# View network locations from Debian shell

Tags: networking, debian, shell, nas, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to see a list of all devices on the network from the shell in debian. The same list you get by typing 'Network' into an explorer window on Windows. Seems like it should be an easy thing to do, but I can't find it on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The absolute best one is to use *nmap*,

```
  sudo apt-get install nmap
```

and then run

```
  sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

If your network is not 192.168.1.0, change accordingly. *nmap* also has a pleasant GUI called *zenmap*, you can install it and run it likewise.

Just one word: *nmap* can do much, much, much more than this.

Comment: Yep.  nmap is the tool du jour.  If you want, you can filter it down to just services on a specific port (file/print sharing only?)

Answer (score 0):

Also look into installing Avahi.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_(software)

```
sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon // daemon
sudo apt-get install avahi-utils // search tools
```